# ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 299 and 3. Shapes are [?,299,299,3] and [1,3,299,299]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I put down this in the command line:

```
    python3 -m tf2onnx.convert \
--graphdef /Users/penghaiming/Desktop/Tensorflowmodel/tensorflow_models/research/slim/frozen.pb \ 
--output model.onnx \
--inputs input:0[1,3,299,299] \
--outputs InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape:0
```

And I have such error:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 752, in set_shape
unknown_shape) 
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 299 and 3. Shapes are [?,299,299,3] and [1,3,299,299].
```

and this:

```
ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 299 and 3. Shapes are [?,299,299,3] and [1,3,299,299].
```

So I actually never write any file on my own. I'm completely new to TensorFlow and I just try to go through the whole process from training to applying the model to CoreML. I used all the code they provided me and went through many difficulties. And This happen when I try to convert my frozen graph to onnx model. Could you help me with the problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like the channel dimensions are in different positions. What is the expected input shape to the model you're trying to convert? Is it enough to specify `--inputs input:0[1,299,299,3]`?

Comment: @AaronKeesing I think the expected input shape is [?,299,299,3]. I actually solve the problem by to delete the whole [1,299,299,3] part. But thank you anyway. I really have not dived too deep into whole TensorFlow syntax and codes, I just keep following the instruction in the slim and solve the problem comes out. It is quite confusing a lot of the time.